# Struts 2 Model driven negative integer

Tags: java, struts2, negative-number, model-driven

How to assign a negative number (-123 or -123.00) to a ModelDriven bean **(implements ModelDriven< Bean >).**
When i try passing the value through request for that action it throws below exception

```
Fri Aug 10 18:45:27 IST 2012 unable to convert value using type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter]
Overflow or underflow casting: "-123.12" into class java.lang.Double - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToNumber(XWorkBasicConverter.java:406)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToNumber(XWorkBasicConverter.java:415)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:118)
```

Comment: How is the source variable declared?

Comment: variable in modeldriven bean is declare as Float ;

Comment: I think this is a known bug with that version of Struts2 which was fixed in later versions, but the bug tracker seems to be down for maintenance at the moment so I can't double check right now.

Comment: @nmc same im too trying for bugtracker couple of hrs to find out in which version it is fixed.

Comment: @nmc There is an ongoing issue with the Apache JIRA instance.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XW-676 is the only bug I could find with regards to your issue. Strange that it says the bug was in v 2.1.2 and fixed in 2.1.3 because I do see a comment that it was still present in 2.1.6.