# struts2 : Invalid field value for field?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

```
<s:iterator value="company.locations"  status="s" ><br>
<s:hidden name="company.locations[%{#s.index}].position.longitude" value="%{position.longitude}" ></s:hidden>
.....
```

i get position from google map, when i send them to struts action, they work fine as long as they are a positive numbers. otherwise (negative number) it give me this error:

Invalid field value for field "company.locations[0].position.longitude" in the

```
<s:fielderror />
```

> the latitude and longitude are double

class graph:

> company > List< Location >
>
> Location > Position(latitude, longitude)

```
<s:hidden name="company.locations[%{#s.index}].position.longitude" value="%{position.longitude}" ></s:hidden>
```

i don't use validation for this fields
i redefined validate method only for redirection purpose, no validation staff in it.

what could be the problem, help me please?

Comment: you may find some help here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902777/struts-2-model-driven-negative-integer

Comment: thank very much for your replay, i have changed struts libs to newer ones and it worked. thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used a newer struts libraries, and this solved my problem.

Comment: it doesn't explain the cause

Comment: this means that there is a problem with the version of libraries that i used before.

Comment: you didn't use any library, even if you did then you should explain how it does solve the problem.

Comment: man i think i am clear i changed struts libraries by a newer version and that solved my problem, and that mean that the libraries that i was using contain bugs. and why and how could you say " 
you didn't use any library". how could i work on struts without it's libraries.

Comment: By means "you didn't use any library" I say that you didn't write in the answer which library replacement solved the problem, what the bug # did it resolve, any link to bug-tracking database? Say that I've just used newer libraries doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OK but sorry i don't have an answer to that, it's been a while that i worked on that small project, i lost it know. the problem that it solve is my problem describing above. it start accepting the negative numbers. anyway i think the struts libraries available now must work without problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason this can happen. I was a little sloppy and had two setters like this...

```
    public String myField="";
    public void setMyField(String value) {
      myField=value;
    }

    public SomeOtherObject someOtherValue;
    public void setMyField(SomeOtherObject value) {
      someOtherValue=value;
    }
```

... which invalidated myField (i.e. the response was "Invalid field value for field myField").

Answer (score 1):

you need to make one youractionclassname.properties file which is from youractionclassname.java in same package.and add properties file to `"invalid.fieldvalue.*=*"`, then it resolves.